# match data of string with data in text file and if matches then "check" the item of checked list box

Tags: c#

I have loaded the data of textfile in the checkedlistbox on form load. I have to match the ip address received in the variable "ip" with ip addresses existing in text file and if a match occurs I have to check mark the corresponding item of the checkedListBox which i loaded earlier. This is my code:

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        server_client a=new server_client();
        Form1 b=new Form1();


        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {    
            int j;
            string ip;
            IPEndPoint localIpEndPoint = b._clientsockets[i].LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
            ip = IPAddress.Parse(((IPEndPoint)b._clientsockets[i].LocalEndPoint).Address.ToString()).ToString();
            string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\cdac_utility1\WindowsApplication1\TextFile1.txt");
            for (j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            {
                if (readText[j] == ip)
                {


                }
            }
        }

        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\cdac_utility1\WindowsApplication1\TextFile1.txt");

        //Now read the file line by line
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //add the line to CheckedListBox, you need to pass the parameters     "index"     & "string"
            checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(counter, line);

            //increase the index
            counter++;
        }

        //close the file
        file.Close();
    }
```

I am not able to check mark the corresponding item in the checkedlistbox which I have to mark on successful matching.

Comment: what do you mean "mark the corresponding item"?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(counter, true);
```